# Generating constructor invocation with type arguments

Tags: java, code-generation, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

I want to use [`TreeMaker`](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.0/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-java-source/org/netbeans/api/java/source/TreeMaker.html) to generate a constructor call for a type with type arguments in my netbeans code generator plugin. Additionally I want to import types rather than using the fully qualified names (see [`QualIdent`](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.0/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-java-source/org/netbeans/api/java/source/TreeMaker.html#QualIdent(java.lang.String))).

I'm using the [`NewClass` method](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.0/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-java-source/org/netbeans/api/java/source/TreeMaker.html#NewClass(com.sun.source.tree.ExpressionTree,%20java.util.List,%20com.sun.source.tree.ExpressionTree,%20java.util.List,%20com.sun.source.tree.ClassTree)) for this purpose.

#### Example:

Given input `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.lang.Integer` the generated code should look similar to this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

...

new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If the input is `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>` the generated code should look similar to this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

...

new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

(The type argument list is stored as `List<? extends TypeMirror>`)

How can I generate the desired output?

#### What I've tried so far:

(`maker` is the `TreeMaker` instance)

1. Convert type name to a string:

   ```
   String className = "java.util.ArrayList<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>"; // actually computed in real code

   maker.NewClass(null,
                  Collections.<ExpressionTree>emptyList(),
                  maker.QualIdent(className),
                  Collections.<ExpressionTree>emptyList(),
                  null);
   ```

   This yields syntactically/semantically correct java code, but uses the fully qualified class names, i.e. `new java.util.ArrayList<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>()`
2. Pass as `typeArguments` to `NewClass`:

   ```
   List<ExpressionTree> typeArguments = Collections.singletonList(maker.QualIdent("java.lang.Integer")); // actually computed in real code

   maker.NewClass(null,
           typeArguments,
           maker.QualIdent("java.util.ArrayList"),
           Collections.<ExpressionTree>emptyList(),
           null);
   ```

   This does import `ArrayList`, but the type arguments are added directly after the `new` keyword, i.e. `new <Integer>ArrayList()` is generated, which is wrong.
3. Use a [`ParameterizedTypeTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/ParameterizedTypeTree.html) as identifier for the type, which doesn't work, since `TreeMaker` expects a parameter of type `ExpressionTree`, but that's not a supertype of `ParameterizedTypeTree`.